# Action bar Tabview preloading in android

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbar, swipeview

I am using http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/ to make Tab bar. I have also 3 tab first and the second Tab view contains a List view. So when i launching the application the first tab is working and show the List at the same time the second list is also Loaded. I want to load the second tab only when i move to the Second view. How can I doing this?

Comment: How can you say the second tab is also loaded ?

Comment: I created the second list view by calling an api. So when i launch the application the tabs Api is also calling.